# Does using the windows repair disk to repair the MBR after uninstalling Ubuntu partitions delete your files and programs?

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, ubuntu, boot

After reading the articles [How to Uninstall a Linux Dual-Boot System From Your Computer](http://www.howtogeek.com/141818/how-to-uninstall-a-linux-dual-boot-system-from-your-computer/) and [How to Manually Repair Windows 7 Boot Loader Problems](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/) (on howtogeek.com) in order to uninstall Ubuntu on a dual- boot system with Windows 7, I was wondering if following the instructions given to repair the MBR would result in a loss of files and programs from the computer it was used on, or if the computer would be as it was before, but without Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Those instructions are indeed meant to show you how to get rid of the Linux installation, including its partitions.  The partitions are where the files are saved on your drives.

If you have important data on one of those Linux partitions, you'd need to back it up first from Linux before following those steps.  At first glance, the tutorials you link to seem to be quite comprehensive and fairly easy to use, but your question implies insecurities that can only be corrected by experience.

Although the instructions appear pretty safe to use, it may be a good idea to request assistance from someone a bit more comfortable with them.

If all goes well as shown, the computer should be quite similar to what it was before installing Linux.